# Cobb-Douglas function homotheticity

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, preferences, cobb-douglas

I've been given the Cobb-Douglas utility function:

$\ u(q_1, q_2)=a\ln q_1+b\ln q_2=q_1^aq_2^b  \ $

If I want to prove homothetic preferences, I use the following condition:

$\ u(\lambda q_1, \lambda q_2)=\lambda u(q_1,q_2)  \ $

According to my calculation, this yields:

$\ u(\lambda q_1, \lambda q_2)=(\lambda q_1)^a(\lambda q_2)^b  \ $

$\ =\ \lambda^{a+b}q_1^aq_2^b   \ $

Is it correct to say that as a result, preferences are homothetic if and only if $\ a+b=1  \ $?

Answer (score 1):

This
$$
a\ln q_1+b\ln q_2=q_1^aq_2^b
$$
is not true, only
$$
a\ln q_1+b\ln q_2=\ln(q_1^aq_2^b)
$$
is true.

$$
u(\lambda q_1, \lambda q_2)=\lambda u(q_1,q_2) 
$$
is a sufficient, but not necessary condition for homotheticity of $u$. You can find more on this by searching for questions with the word [homothetic](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=homothetic) on this site.

It is indeed true that 
$$
\lambda^{a+b}q_1^aq_2^b = \lambda q_1^aq_2^b
$$
if $a+b = 1$.